# CSS positioning isn't moving the image?

Tags: html, css

So I'm in the process of making a drag and drop browser 'dress up' type game. However, for some reason, I can't seem to position my images - either the draggable image or the doll base. I am able to drag and drop the draggable image, but I can't change their initial positions. 
I've changed their position types, tried using top/bottom/left/right, margin, and even padding to move the images to where I want them, but they absolutely will not move!

Here's the HTML/CSS I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<style> 
<!--Page Styling-->
html, body{
    background-color:#5C5C5C;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 #banner{
background: rgb(143,250,138); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(143,250,138,1) 0%, rgba(127,239,127,1) 10%, rgba(109,223,115,1) 25%, rgba(107,229,115,1) 37%, rgba(106,236,114,1) 50%, rgba(74,226,82,1) 51%, rgba(136,242,122,1) 83%, rgba(175,252,142,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(143,250,138,1)), color-stop(10%,rgba(127,239,127,1)), color-stop(25%,rgba(109,223,115,1)), color-stop(37%,rgba(107,229,115,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(106,236,114,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(74,226,82,1)), color-stop(83%,rgba(136,242,122,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(175,252,142,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(143,250,138,1) 0%,rgba(127,239,127,1) 10%,rgba(109,223,115,1) 25%,rgba(107,229,115,1) 37%,rgba(106,236,114,1) 50%,rgba(74,226,82,1) 51%,rgba(136,242,122,1) 83%,rgba(175,252,142,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(143,250,138,1) 0%,rgba(127,239,127,1) 10%,rgba(109,223,115,1) 25%,rgba(107,229,115,1) 37%,rgba(106,236,114,1) 50%,rgba(74,226,82,1) 51%,rgba(136,242,122,1) 83%,rgba(175,252,142,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(143,250,138,1) 0%,rgba(127,239,127,1) 10%,rgba(109,223,115,1) 25%,rgba(107,229,115,1) 37%,rgba(106,236,114,1) 50%,rgba(74,226,82,1) 51%,rgba(136,242,122,1) 83%,rgba(175,252,142,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(143,250,138,1) 0%,rgba(127,239,127,1) 10%,rgba(109,223,115,1) 25%,rgba(107,229,115,1) 37%,rgba(106,236,114,1) 50%,rgba(74,226,82,1) 51%,rgba(136,242,122,1) 83%,rgba(175,252,142,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8ffa8a', endColorstr='#affc8e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
width: 100%;
margin-left: -10px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 99999;
position: fixed;
}

#holder{
position: absolute;
height: 800px;
width: 900px;
background-color: #838B8B;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-top: -300px;
z-index: -1;
}
<!--Bodies-->
#body1 {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
height: auto;
width: 200px;
z-index: 1;
}
<!--Parts-->
#breath{
position: relative;
left: 10px;
}
  </style> 

<!--Draggable Scripts-->
  <script> 
  $(function() { 
    $( "#breath" ).draggable(); 
  }); 
  </script> 
<!--End Draggable Scripts-->

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="banner">Homestuck Character Editor</div>
<div id="body1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/aO3GWBO.png"draggable="false"/></div>
<div id="holder"></div>
<div id="breath"> 
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iAmOFlH.png"/>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where should they be?

Comment: here is your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p9y9k/

Comment: The draggable image is supposed to be slightly off the left, and the non-draggable is supposed to be on the right. I added in the positioning codes, but they don't move.

Answer (score 1):

You positioned the `div` on the right, but the image is still on the left.  Since `div` elements are blocks, they fill 100% of their parent.  In this case, the parent is 100%. You can get the image on the right side of the screen by selecting it, and shifting the image itself.  I used the following:

```
#body1 img {
  position:absolute;
  right:0; 
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9y9k/1/).